# I'm just trying to remove the single item from a session[cart_item]

Tags: php

I used a session for adding an item in my page without database. here i have one problem while trying to remove this file in my page. here is my code for link for remove. I used to select data by its title variable.

```
<a href="step3.php?action=remove&title=<?php echo $item["title"]; ?>" class="product-title">
    <span class="label label-warning pull-right">Remove</span>
</a>
```

I used switch case to select remove operation.

```
case "remove":
    if(!empty($_SESSION["cart_item"])) {
        foreach($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $k => $v) {
            if($_GET["title"] == $k)
                unset($_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]);              
            if(empty($_SESSION["cart_item"]))
                unset($_SESSION["cart_item"]);
        }
    }
break;
```

it select the title variable perfectly. but remove action is not performing.

here also i dont have any unique value for select an single data from session... give some solutions too..

Comment: Why do you need that loop? Why not just `unset($_SESSION['"cart_item"][$_GET["code"]])`?

Comment: `$_GET["code"]`? Are you sure this is correct?

Comment: no.. this $_GET["title"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass parameter "code" or else "cart_item" should be empty but your verifying it should not be empty in first if condition **if(!empty($_SESSION["cart_item"]))** 
 verify your condition:

```
case "remove":
    if(!empty($_SESSION["cart_item"])) { //condition 1
        foreach($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $k => $v) {
                if($_GET["code"] == $k)
                    unset($_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]);              
                if(empty($_SESSION["cart_item"]))// condition 2 wont work 
                    unset($_SESSION["cart_item"]);
        }
    }
break;
```

Comment: how it should be empty..!!, its have the variable when the session starts, and if i print those variables means, its show the value....@Ananthakumar

Answer (score 0):

`if($_GET["code"] == $k)`
should be
`if($_GET["title"] == $k)`

Answer (score 0):

You haven't pass `$_GET["code"]` through the link.
Shouldn't it be `$_GET["title"] == $k` ?

Comment: s.. I also try with $_GET["title"], still it have the same problem.. @RysQ

Answer (score 0):

In your URL you are passing `action` and `title` no `code`.

So it should be

```
case "remove":
    if(!empty($_SESSION["cart_item"])) {
        foreach($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $k => $v) {
            if($_GET["title"] == $k)
                unset($_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]);              
            if(empty($_SESSION["cart_item"]))
                unset($_SESSION["cart_item"]);
        }
    }
break;
```

Comment: obviously.. the action go to that switch case variable "remove". this s not a problem

Comment: @RubhanSingh no look at `$_GET["code"]`  in your code. Actually you are not dont have any variable called $_GET["code"] thats what everyone mean

Comment: yes, When i used to put "if($_GET["code"] == $k)" in that remove part,  i changed my link like this "<a href="step3.php?action=remove&title=<?php echo $item["code"]; ?>" class="product-title">". but problem is not there, because it shows the correct value, when i print that variable...

Comment: @RubhanSingh hopefully other answer helped and fixed your issue right?

Comment: s im waiting for.. bt i try all the commands people suggest here, and then only give a reply for them... i need an answer to solve my prob..

Comment: @PadmaRubhan is your problem solved or not? Since you accepted answer I thought your issue has been resolved? Still the issue persist?